# how to specify scope in html5 login buttons

Tags: html, facebook

[Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0) gives the following as an example of how to create a login button for a facebook app:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

That URL also refers you to [Login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button) for more details. That link has a login button generator. Using the default values I click on the "Get Link" button and am presented with four options: HTML5, XFBML, IFRAME and URL. Clicking on the latter two gives me a "*This plugin does not support this type of embedding. Please use the JavaScript SDK and the XFBML or HTML5 implementations*" message.

The XFBML link is the one that more closely resembles the login button from the "Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK" URL. But let's say I wanted to use the HTML5 code. **How do I use scope and onlogin with the HTML5 code?**

Does the HTML5 code support the `scope` and `onlogin` attributes? If I use those [the code](http://pastebin.com/t6PUAARj) won't be [valid HTML5](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). Maybe I should use `data-scope` or `data-onlogin`? Maybe the HTML5 code doesn't support `scope` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have linked the [Login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button) page yourself. At the part about [Settings](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button#settings), the HTML5 attributes are listed for each feature.

- The HTML5 attribute for `scope` is `data-scope` as you have guessed.
- The HTML5 attribute for `onlogin` is simply `onlogin`.

Honestly I'm surprised about the latter as `data-onlogin` would be more logical. Maybe it's a typo, maybe it's mimicking the existing `onload`, `onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc... event handler attributes.